# Advice on negatively skewed residuals

Tags: distributions, anova, skewness, qq-plot

I am running a simple one-way ANOVA of a continuous dependent variable and my two-level categorical independent variable.  n value = 408; 198 in my control condition and 210 in my experimental condition (the two-level categorical variable).  I've run some diagnostics on the model outcome and the Q-Q plot is looking very non-normal.  Does this indicate negative skew?  I have tried a variety of transformations but nothing seems to improve it...  [image]

Do you think this is so bad that I would have to resort to a non-parametric alternative such as Mann-Whitney/Kruskal Wallis?

I have a second continuous dependent variable that I am running against the same two-level categorical variable (similar n numbers here too).  For this the distribution may even be slightly worse.  Could I have some advice on this second plot too?[image]

Any advice in interpreting these diagnostic plots and possible solutions would be very, very much appreciated.  Sorry that I cannot paste the data here - I need to keep it confidential for ethical reasons...

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What are these data? What are the n's?

Comment: I wouldn't worry much myself about non-normality here. The bigger deal is that your means appear to be about 5.22 and 5.44. How does the difference compare with what is scientifically or practically important? What P-value do you get associated with the predictor coefficient?  A t-test is an alternative here to ANOVA, and (what's perhaps important) t-test software will typically include some options for you to explore the sensitivity of your result. Nothing rules out other tests, but those mentioned test quite different hypotheses.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment @NickCox! Effect size is quite small - it's for a scale representing an average score on an index of risk perception. Using the total scores the difference in means is ~2, so still small but I believe it is worth reporting in the context of my data/hypotheses.  In terms of the p value - AOV gives p=0.0468 and t-test p=0.0471.  Wilcoxon test gives p=0.0325.  So significant but not very strongly so.  I plan to report the results with ref to the small effect size - I was just unsure whether the state of my residuals would mean I should...

Comment: (sorry - ran out of space!) report only the Wilcoxon results, or whether I could be safe in using AOV/t-test. Would you recommend both do you think?

Also, forgive the simplicity of this question, but why would you recommend using a t-test rather than one-way anova?  Is it because the t-test is a bit more robust to deviations from normality in the residuals?  Thank you so much again!

Comment: ps n value = 408; 198 in my control condition and 210 in my experimental (the survey software I used randomly allocated so not even between the two.  Can the t.test/aov/wilcox functions in R/SPSS deal with this or should I specify the imbalance between the two groups?

Comment: @NickCox I do apologise for yet another comment - I have added a second series of q-q plots for a slightly different reponse variable.  The effect size is much larger and p value <0.001 for both t-test and aov.  Could I possibly have some advice on whether the distributions are ok for this too, or whether I should go for a non-parametric test?  Thank you so, so much again...

Comment: My recommendation of the t-test rests on the possibility of specifying unequal variances. It's folklore that t-tests work quite well with moderate non-normality (that doesn't necessarily include data with outliers). R.G. Miller, _Beyond ANOVA_ is an outstanding help if you can get hold of it.

Comment: Thank you so much again.  Can I ask one final favour and have your thoughts on the second plot I added to my post?